# The spool table created by ejabberd on MySQL doesn't have a PK. Is this a bug or a feature?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, ejabberd, spool

Is this a bug (I could manually create a PK for it), or is this a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the current mysql.sql from the ejabberd 2.1.x branch for additional context at https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/2.1.x/src/odbc/mysql.sql .

```
    CREATE TABLE spool (
        username varchar(250) NOT NULL,
        xml text NOT NULL,
        seq BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
        created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

It looks like the "seq" column is a unique identifier that can be used the same way as a primary key except that no foreign key references can be made to it.  I expect this is unimportant because there is never a time in ejabberd when you need to reference a particular offline message by its sequence number in another mysql table by way of a foreign key constraint.

I'm sure someone at processone had an opinion about this that resulted in a unique constraint instead of a primary key.  Having worked extensively with mod_offline_odbc I can assure you that it won't make a difference to ejabberd if you add "primary_key(seq)" to the spool table definition and remove the redundant unique constraint on the seq column.

Comment: That is highly curious and I'm not sure how to account for it.  Is there any reason you need a primary key instead of a unique constraint?

Comment: I monitor the table with a tool/library that refuses to work with tables that don't have PK. I'm guessing it's a bug in the tool.

Comment: I may be assuming a bit much, but if you are looking for notifications about the existence of offline messages it is fairly easy to write a custom module that watches the offline message hook.  From there you can do an http post to a web server using the inets application or pass messages to something like rabbitmq.

Comment: That is correct.  For what it's worth, the module I suggested is a fairly trivial one.  I have written such a module in an afternoon.